# Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object in elastic-builder

Tags: node.js, typescript, elasticsearch, npm, elastic-builder

I am trying to use [elastic-builder](https://github.com/sudo-suhas/elastic-builder) to build my elasticsearch query. I want to separate parts of the process into nodejs modules.
This way I can build complex queries on the fly and reuse the modules across services.

When I refactor some of the parts into modules I receive this error:
`Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

I have tried building the query within the same application and it works.

service/index.ts

```js
import esb from 'elastic-builder';

const run = () => {

  // add any customers filters here
  const boolBody =  esb.boolQuery().must(esb.regexpQuery('catch_all', `.*test.*`).flags('NONE'));

  // apply the sorting here
  const s = esb.sort('catch_all', 'asc').missing('_last').mode('max').unmappedType('keyword');

  // build the base query here
  const body = esb.requestBodySearch().query(boolBody).sort(s);

  console.log(JSON.stringify(body.toJSON(), null, 2));

};

run();
```

I moved some of the logic to modules and that's when the error occurs and the process is unsuccessful.

service/index.ts

```js
import esb from 'elastic-builder';
import { ToElasticFilter } from 'filtermodule';
import { ToElasticSort } from 'sortmodule';

const run = () => {

  // add any customers filters here
  const boolBody = ToElasticFilter(); // esb.boolQuery().must(esb.regexpQuery('catch_all', `.*test.*`).flags('NONE'));

  // apply the sorting here
  const s = ToElasticSort(); // esb.sort('catch_all', 'asc').missing('_last').mode('max').unmappedType('keyword');

  // build the base query here
  const body = esb.requestBodySearch().query(boolBody).sort(s);

  console.log(JSON.stringify(body.toJSON(), null, 2));

};

run();
```

The refactored module files look like this:

filterModule/index.ts

```js
import esb from 'elastic-builder';

export function ToElasticFilter(): esb.Query {
  return esb
    .regexpQuery('catch_all', `.*test.*`)
    .flags('NONE')
}
```

sortModule/index.ts

```js
import esb from 'elastic-builder';

export function ToElasticSort(): esb.Sort {
  return esb.sort('catch_all', 'asc')
    .missing('_last')
    .mode('max')
    .unmappedType('keyword');
}
```

[A full view of the project is here](https://github.com/DarrenMa/esb_modules_sample/tree/main)